# All the electronics, singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, all-of

I want to say that all the components of my robot are inside the robot, should I use *is* or *are*?

> All the electronics are hidden inside the robot, only the power cable is visible outside of it.

In French, I would use singular because we're considering Electronics as one whole stuff. But I am not sure about English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dictionary (Chambers, 13edn) provides the definition

> (*n sing*) the science and technology of the conduction of electricity
> in a vacuum, a gas or a semi-conductor

but it also provides

> (*n pl*) the electronic parts of a machine or system

and it's that second definition which you are using in your example sentence so *are* is correct.

Comment: I was about to CV, and DV the answer, as GENREF, but the first dictionary I checked in was unhelpful, the second unclear without easy access to their labelling; Collins is very clear. // Chambers is misleading; the first sense is **noun non-count** (plural in form) (taking a singular verb form). It is **not** a 'singular noun'.